# Assets not retrieving URL for second site

Tags: multi-site-manager, assets

My situation:
I have 3 sites (2 photoblogs, 1 start page). The 2 photoblogs use Assets to manage the images and CE Image to make the thumbnails.

My problem:
on the start page i use (this is a simple example just to get the URL from assets in their respective entries for all sites):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="fotoblog" site="site1|site2" limit="1"}
 {fotoblog-imagens limit="1"}{url}{/fotoblog-imagens}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**{fotoblog-imagens} is an Assets field**

Only site1 returns the URL. Site2 doesn't. If i erase Site1 from the site field, it now returns the URLs for the Assets in entries on Site2. Tried var_prefix but results are the same. Any tips?

Comment: Vitor - can you add some version numbers? EE, Assets, MSM? Thank you!

Comment: EE - 2.6.1
MSM - 2.1.5
Assets - 2.1.3

Comment: That should not be a problem.  Is Wygwam involved here at all?  Are login details to your site available by any chance?  Super Admin access specifically.  If so, can you email those to support@pixelandtonic.com so that I can look directly? Thank you!

Comment: Wygwam addon is installed, but it's not called. just expressionengine entries and Assets. I've sent you guys an email.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you'll need to do is add site_id="site1" to your assets loop.

{exp:channel:entries channel="fotoblog" site="site1|site2" limit="1"}
 {fotoblog-imagens limit="1" site="site1"}{url}{/fotoblog-imagens}
{/exp:channel:entries}

I think that should get it working.

Comment: I'ts a bug in Assets module. Pixel and Tonic has solved. The fix will come on the next update (currently 2.1.3)

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work. Can you provide correct template tags?

Comment: If you are replying to me Jon, I'd first update Assets. Victor mentioned that it was a bug. If you want to try the code I suggested, I am presuming you are replacing 'site1' with the short name of your site?